# How can we insert a composite primary key in N:M table using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So, we have a table named **category_has_serviceprovider** that has a composite primary key **(idCategory, idUser)** and we have a table **timeslots** with a primary key **(idTimeSlots)**.

What we want to do is: we want to build a **N:M** table in sequelize using the table **category_has_serviceprovider** and **timeslots**. The result should be the table **category_x_timeslots** that you can see in the next image:

[image]

As you can see it has a composite primary key **(idTimeSlots, idCategory, idUser)**, but when we do it in sequelize we get the next image:

[image]

So, you can see that it is missing the **idUser** from **category_has_serviceprovider**. Can we achieve this in sequelize?

The code that we have for the **category_x_timeslots** table is:

```
const Category_has_ServiceProvider = require("../../category_has_serviceProvider/api/category_has_serviceProvider");
const TimeSlots = require("../../timeslots/api/timeslots");

const category_x_TimeSlots = dbconfig.sequelize.define('Category_x_TimeSlots', {
    occupied : {
        type: dbconfig.Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false
    },
    experience : {
        type: dbconfig.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
});

Category_has_ServiceProvider.belongsToMany(TimeSlots, {foreignKey: 'idCategory', through: category_x_TimeSlots});
TimeSlots.belongsToMany(Category_has_ServiceProvider, {foreignKey: 'idTimeSlots',through: category_x_TimeSlots});


category_x_TimeSlots.sync()

module.exports = category_x_TimeSlots;
```

Tell me if you need to see the other 2 tables implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think composite foreign keys are only supported at query level and they are not created at the database. As an alternative for the database i would suggest the junction table to have a autoIncrement primary key ( id) and add indexes at the foreign keys columns which should be manually defined.

```
const Category_has_ServiceProvider = require("../../category_has_serviceProvider/api/category_has_serviceProvider");
const TimeSlots = require("../../timeslots/api/timeslots");

const category_x_TimeSlots = dbconfig.sequelize.define('Category_x_TimeSlots', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    occupied: {
        type: dbconfig.Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false
    },
    experience: {
        type: dbconfig.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    idCategory: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    idUser: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    idTimeSlots: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [{
        unique: true,
        fields: ['idCategory', 'idUser', 'idTimeSlots']
    }]
});

Category_has_ServiceProvider.belongsToMany(TimeSlots, {foreignKey: ['idCategory', 'idUser'], through: category_x_TimeSlots});
TimeSlots.belongsToMany(Category_has_ServiceProvider, {foreignKey: 'idTimeSlots',through: category_x_TimeSlots});


category_x_TimeSlots.sync()

module.exports = category_x_TimeSlots;
```